# Different HTML files for each slide in ionic slide box

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

Working with ionic version 1.3.18

I've got a slide box working fine, but I'll probably need to put quite a bit of content into each slide so I was wondering if it were possible to have a separate file for each slide like the way you can with ionic tabs?

Attempting the following:

```
<ion-slide href="#/slide1">
```

didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a nav view inside ion-slide -

```
<ion-nav-view name='viewname'></ion-nav-view>
```

Where `viewname` points to your template (you might have to set this up in your route too).

Comment: Routes are all set up for the different pages, but it only loads the first page. When I put the view name in, it doesn't redirect to that route, it just stays as the firs route loaded.

Comment: Did you add a new view for this in your routes? Nested views work pretty well. If you can add some code in plnkr/jsfiddle/codepen then others might be able to help you better.